# What happens to a function generator waveform when another capacitor is added in parallel with an existing capacitor in a circuit?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, electric-circuits, electric-fields, wavefunction

I am trying to gain an understanding of the first-order response of RC circuits and measurement of capacitance in a capacitive sensor using function generation and oscilloscopes. I had a question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding more capacitance between the two terminals of the function generator furnishes an easier path to ground for the high frequency content of the function generator's output. If you are generating square waves, the sharp edges of the waveform will become progressively more rounded off and smoothed out as you add capacitance.

If you are generating sine waves, then the overall amplitude of the sine wave signal will decrease as the capacitance is increased.

The size of these changes will depend on the frequency at which the function generator is set and the size of the capacitors in farads. Setting the generator for higher frequencies, and adding lots of capacitance, will furnish the biggest change.

Comment: Note that this works because function generators typically have a 50 ohm resistive impedance on generation end (or some resistance at least), so when capacitors connect the terminals, the main voltage drop at high frequencies is across this internal resistance.